# Matlab sometimes plots scatterplot below shapefile

Tags: matlab

I am drawing a map and then plotting a scatter plot on top of it using Matlab 2010.

It takes an input file reads it in.
Transforms it into the proper arrays. Then I use.

```
hold on;
geoshow('landareas.shp');
scatterm(lat, lon, 1, log(z), 's', 'filled');
```

For a while it always did it correctly. Then every once in a while it would plot them backwards. Then It happened more frequently, and now it seems like it randomly chooses some input files to always plot backwards and some to always plot correctly. To the best of my knowledge nothing has changed in the code.

This is making me feel like I'm going crazy. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `uistack` to define the plotting order.

With your code:

```
hold on;
geoshow('landareas.shp');
h = scatterm(lat, lon, 1, log(z), 's', 'filled');

% Bring the scatter plot to top
uistack(h,'top');
```

Best,